# Connecting to Spark Standalone cluster from Airflow

Tags: docker, apache-spark, airflow, spark-submit, apache-spark-standalone

I've airflow running on local env using docker-compose file and spark standalone cluster also running on local. I logged into airflow worker container and tried to submit the spark job to standalone spark cluster but connection to master node is getting refused.

1. airflow is running on localhost:8080
2. spark standalone cluster is running on localhost:8090
3. Spark Master at spark://spark-master:7077

NOTE: I checked that JAVA_HOME path is properly set, both the airflow and spark standalone containers are running on same docker network but still I'm unable to submit the job.

**command: spark-submit --master spark://spark-master:7077 ./dags/my-script.py**

I tried all combination of --master value but no luck.

Can anyone suggest if I'm missing something

Comment: Are you using a BashOperator from Airflow?